# COUNT returns ambiguous result for LEFT JOIN query with NULLs

Tags: count, abap, opensql

Is possible to `count` the `left join`'ed records? I would like to see `count` return the actual records joined (including `0` if nothing is left joined).

A join like the following worked in other forms of SQL I worked with, but OpenSQL does not seem to support `count([column])`:

```
select header~key, count(item~key) 
from header left join item on header~key = item~header_key
group by header~key.
```

I know the following query works, but **if there are no `items` joined with a header, count will still be 1** and not 0:

```
select header~key, count(*) from header left join item group by header~key.
```

For now I have resorted to using abap (`loop` and `loop at` with `group` addition) for counting when I needed that. 
In my current scenario I am dealing with transaction data, which is massive in comparison to my previous projects and an extra loop increases processing time considerably.

Comment: You need to know when there is no "Item"? You can separate it in two querys

Comment: That would be much better if you could correct your post by using tildes instead of dashes in the column names.

Comment: @I.B.N. Yes, I have the means to achieve the results using "workarounds", but SQL for all big DB engines have this functionality built in so I figured there might be a better way to do this, than looping through thousands of headers and selecting counts for each one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that DISTINCT is mandatory, i.e. [COUNT( DISTINCT col )](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselect_aggregate.htm).

This works in 7.52.

EDIT : I removed my first query after discussing with Suncatcher, and added the more detailed answer below.

Of course DISTINCT does not count duplicate values, so you could count the concatenation (DISTINCT CONCAT( … )) of all columns of the primary key.

Let me show you the contents of SCARR and SPFLI, and then the final result.

Table SCARR :

```
CARRID
------
FJ
JL
LH
NG
```

Table SPFLI :

```
CARRID  CONNID
------  ------
JL      0407
JL      0408
LH      0400
LH      0401
LH      0402
LH      2402
```

Open SQL :

```
SELECT scarr~carrid, 
       COUNT( DISTINCT CONCAT( spfli~carrid, spfli~connid ) ) AS count
  FROM scarr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN spfli ON scarr~carrid = spfli~carrid
  GROUP BY scarr~carrid
  WHERE scarr~carrid IN ('FJ','JL','LH','NG')
  INTO TABLE @DATA(itab).
```

Result :

```
CARRID  COUNT
------  ------
FJ      0
JL      2
LH      4
NG      0
```

Comment: No, `DISTINCT` solves nothing. I checked it with DISTINCT query on my system against my dataset and got the same results as the OP.

Comment: I don't understand what you find wrong in my answer. I get a count of 0 for lines from SCARR for which there's no correspondance in SPFLI, and a count >= 1 when there are some correspondances. Wasn't it the question? Maybe you are using a different release. Moreover, didn't @Zero say that he couldn't use COUNT because it's not accepted? I show here that it's accepted with DISTINCT.

Comment: Try it with some non-key char field (like my sample with `marc-ekgrp`) and you will see it does not work. COUNT is ambiguous on char fields.

Comment: I still don't understand, my answer also works with character fields. To stop the polemics, I added an EDIT in my answer, and you could explain what should be changed in my query (or in table values maybe?) so that it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Concatenating gives nothing as `carrid/connid` are key fields, so it's **never empty**, that's why concatenating is useless for simulating OP's problem. The initial problem was that `item-key` is empty but treated as non-empty. Try my sample with mara/marc.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding of the OP's question, because I understand that he just wants to get COUNT=0 when there are no join in the "item" table (with COUNT(*) he was always getting COUNT=1). Let's wait for the OP...

Comment: Actually this solves my problem. It counts **distinct keys** records of the "optional" side of the join (which I did not think of). Since keys  are always unique (and apparently `null` is not counted), I actually get 0 when selecting `from a left join b where abap_true = abap_false` and correct count when selecting `from a left join b where a~key = b~key`. I'm on 7.5, and it works with single column key (i assume it will work with multi column key too, because functionality is there)

Comment: @SandraRossi - thank you for this great example.  I am working on al older system that complains about the CONCAT aggregate function.  I'd like my code to work as far back as  NW  AS ABAP 7.0.  Any ideas?

Comment: @johnaco No but you can ask the question

Answer (score 0):

The result of the query is correct in the sense that it does exactly what you told it to do:

A left join gives you null values of the right table if there is no match by definition of the left join. You would be counting the null value of the right table if you selected more columns of the right table, which is 1.

So SAP is supporting count and you‘re getting the correct result (not the one you want).

What you want to do is to select item separately to count.
Be careful: if you do this, sy-subrc will always be 0, even if there is no item.

This might be surprising but is also correct, because you‘re getting a result, which is count=0.

Comment: I know that result is correct and understand why it is correct, but what I am trying to achieve is part of standard SQL functionality (in DBs I've worked with so far). The most simple example I can give is: I always have some fields from header, but I also need the count of lines joined to header (so it's never only count). In this scenario count = 0 is valid and cannot be confused with a failed select. By the way, the solution **Sandra Rossi** proposed works perfectly for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting bug (or maybe a feature?) of OpenSQL, and on my system I confirm this.

The explanation lays in [implementation specifics of SQL engine](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenopen_sql_null_values.htm) by SAP:

> When passed to data objects, null values are transformed to
>   type-dependent initial values

So not all empty values in SAP DB database fields are nulls, and SAP often treats those empty values as **valid values**.

I tested this use-case on MARA/MARC tables with field `EKGRP` and con confirm that `COUNT` behaves weirdly on my data, returning a mess on different datasets when the `EKGRP` is empty or have initial value.

What I propose: compare **all** possible empty/NULL values/variants that can contain your comparing field ( `item-key` in your case) and check it in `JOIN ON` condition (!) not in `WHERE` clause.

Look at the sample:

```
SELECT mara~matnr, COUNT( DISTINCT marc~ekgrp ) AS count
 FROM mara
 LEFT OUTER JOIN marc
   ON mara~matnr = marc~matnr
  AND marc~ekgrp IS NOT NULL 
  AND marc~ekgrp NE '' 
  AND marc~ekgrp NE '000'
GROUP BY mara~matnr, marc~ekgrp
 INTO TABLE @DATA(tab).
```

All in all, this is highly database-dependent and field type-dependent, so no simple recipe here. SAP writes:

> However, depending on the database system, empty strings can also be
>   displayed as null values.